# VScode BUILD FAILED Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code, build.gradle

I am trying to code an app for the first time with flutter in vs code and I am getting this error,

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\ajgoc\Desktop\Badges\badges_gram\buddies_gram-master\android\build.gradle' line: 29
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> > 'org.gradle.api.file.DirectoryProperty org.gradle.api.file.ProjectLayout.directoryProperty(org.gradle.api.provider.Provider)'

Exception: Gradle task assembly debug failed with exit code 1

I have tried a couple of things to fix it but haven't gotten anything to work. The app will still load in the emulator but it is an older version of the app. Here is what my `gradle-wrapper.poperties` and `build.gradle` files look like.

[gradle-wrapper.poperties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy1QR.png)

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbw7C.png)

[flutter doctor -v output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyWJ7.png)

Comment: Can you add output from `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: I have uploaded the output form flutter doctor -v

Comment: Unsure if this will help but easy to try: current Flutter 2.5.3-stable uses Gradle 4.1.0. In your build.gradle you're using 3.3.2. You can change the version Flutter uses by changing the value in build.gradle i.e. `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'

Comment: When I tried to change the version and run it, it threw a new error saying, Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: FWIW: ` #windows users: This can be solved by adding environment variable for jdk. Or delete the .gradle folder under C:\users'Your username'\ `  Deleting the .gradle folder is pretty common when trying to troubleshoot gradle errors - don't worry about losing anything. After deleting it, Flutter run or build will download the version of gradle it wants and recreate the folder.